# Debugging a VLAN configuration

Tags: vlan

I need help debugging a VLAN configuration with two servers I have in a datacenter. I have no access over the core switch that is used but the datacenter people told me that they've created a VLAN for me and gave me the ID 333.

NICs are all Intel 82574L, both servers are running ubuntu 14.04. `8021q` is in `/etc/modules`

I've created the VLANs with `vconfig add eth0 333`.

`/etc/network/interfaces` looks like this:

```
# server 1

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
  # ... public IP & GW

auto eth0.333
iface eth0.333 inet static 
    address 192.168.1.10
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    vlan-raw-device eth0
```

---

```
# server 2
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
  # ... public IP & GW

auto eth0.333
iface eth0.333 inet static 
    address 192.168.1.20
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    vlan-raw-device eth0
```

I'm unable to ping the servers using `ping 192.168.1.xxx -I eth0.333` on both servers.

Is there something I can do to see what's actually going on? Where are the packets dropped?

---

Edit:

Ifconfig output

```
eth0.333  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr x:x:x
      inet addr:192.168.1.10  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::225:90ff:fed2:ac70/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:56 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:2664 (2.6 KB)


eth0.333  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr x:x:x
      inet addr:192.168.1.20  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::21b:21ff:fec4:e50/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:77 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:3546 (3.4 KiB)
```

Comment: You could use `wireshark` and capture the packets to see what's going on.

Comment: what is the actual ifconfig output?

Comment: @TorbalanBG added the ifconfig output

Comment: Are the two servers being able to PING each other via the public IP address assigned to their `eth0` interface? Are your servers being able to reach something else, on the network (eg.: the default gateway, or an external, local DNS server) connected to the main `eth0`? How many NIC do your two servers have (`lspci` might help), in addition to `eth0`? Are you working with physical servers of virtual ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your config seems right.

Did the DC guys specifically mention its a tagged vlan? They may have given you the id only for reference and the vlan may not be actually tagged.
You can see if that's the case by just adding the additional addresses to the main interfaces and try ping again.

Another possible reason is if they created the vlan with the wrong switch ports and one of the servers may not be in it. You'll have to double check with the datacenter support.

Comment: So you are saying the switch might be configured to automatically tag all the packages from my servers so that I don't have to do this on my own? I didn't know this was even possible. I'll check that :)

Comment: All managed switches can do that, even the cheapest ones ;)

Comment: Yeah, that makes total sense when I think about it.

Comment: You marked the answer as ok, was it the vlan being untagged?